# tabular data from outlook into excel

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-excel-2010

I receive a lot of automated reports by email everyday. These emails often contain an html table of data. If I want to analyze it, I have to get it into excel. However, I really don't like manually copy/pasting it into excel.

```
headerA   headerB   headerC
dataA1    dataB1    dataC1
dataA2    dataB2    dataC2
etc
```

Is there a plugin for outlook where I can right click on a table and have it open in excel? (preferably with row filters & a pivot table)